What will be the impact force on the shaft which is connected to a rope falling from a height? What will be the calculation approach?
I have a product which has a Steel shaft. This shaft is tied to a rope falling from 0.75m height. Total length of rope is approximately 1.5m. I need to find specifically the impact load which the shaft is going to bear. Please help me understand the physics and calculation behind this problem. Appreciate the help.


Depends greatly on the properties of the rope - how elastic it is.

Its a 4mm diameter nylon rope.
https://www.amazon.in/Add-gearTM-Parachute-Paracord-Military-diameter/dp/B07H2XTF2B?th=1
Like this rope.
